# RxJS 6 - Do I need to unsubscribe when using first in a pipe?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Given the following code

```
function triggerAction() {
    const asyncAction$ = of("value1");
    asyncAction$
        .clientLogin()
        .pipe(
            first(),
            tap(val => console.log(`Test: ${val}`)),
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```

Do I need to unsubscribe? Previously when using first with patched operators, they unsubscribed themselves once the first event was emitted, but it's not immediately clear from the documentation as to if the piped operator equivalent does the same.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/first

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both RxJS 5 and RxJS 6 versions of `first` work the same so you don't need to unsubscribe because it completes the chain and thus triggers dispose handlers.

If you want to be sure you can add `complete` callback to your `tap` and see if it gets called (you could add it to `subscribe` as well):

```
asyncAction$
    .clientLogin()
    .pipe(
        first(),
        tap({
            next: val => console.log(`Test: ${val}`),
            complete: () => console.log(`Complete`),
        }),
    )
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 4):

The subscription$ will unsubscribe when the interval emits the first value.
Beware, even if the AppComponent is destroyed the subscription$ will not unsubscribe until the interval emits a value.

So it is best to make sure everything is cancelled in the ngOnDestroy hook.